# facing an 'unhandled promise rejections' error from express, issue with catch() statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, cheerio

i'm facing an error ' Unhandled promise rejections' when ever i run this code :
`

```
app.get('/standings/:tableId', async (req, res) => {
    
  const tableId = req.params.tableId
  
  const tableAddress = tables.filter(table => table.id == tableId)[0].address
  const team_ID = tables.filter(table => table.id == tableId) [0].id
  
  const results = [];
  try {
    const result = await request.get(tableAddress);

    const $ = cheerio.load(result);

    $('#league-tables-wrapper > div > div.table-wrapper > table > tbody > tr').each((index, element) => {
     
        const tds = $(element).find("td");
        const rank = $(tds[0]).text();
        const team = $(tds[2]).text();
        const points = $(tds[10]).text();
        const tableRow = { rank, team, points };
        results.push({
            rank,
            team,
            points
        });
    });

  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
    
   res.json(results)
});
```

`

the error says that it is 'not possible to read property address of undefined' from this list :
`

```
const tables = [
    {
        address: 'https://****/****/superliga',
        id: 'Albania',
        league: 'superliga'
    },
    {
        address: 'https://****/****/ligue-1',
        id: 'Algeria',
        league: 'ligue 1'
    },
```

`
the resume of the error is :
**This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()**
but i already have a catch statement.

can anyone tell me what is the issue with my code. i'm using express, cheerio and request-promise

Comment: If your code throws then you'll try to send 2 responses, which causes an error. `res.json(results)` should be in the `try` block. I think you mean `tables.find()` rather than `tables.filter()`. `filter` returns an array which has no such properties `.address` and `.id`. But `.find()` can return null on failure so you should check this too. There may be other problems; a [mcve] would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems with your code, however, to answer your question exactly : your `try ... catch` is useless in that context. What you actually need to write is :

```
app.get('/standings/:tableId')
   .then((req,res) => {your_whole_code_here})
   .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

if you want your async errors to be caught correctly.

Also try triple equality for your Id `tables.filter(table => table.id === tableId)[0].address` and check that `tableId` corresponds to the format of your table Ids, because your filter just returns an empty array in that case.